# how to get view of action bar with action items to display all activities in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Hi my application contains many activities. I create some action-items that display to the action-bar. How to display that action-bar with action-items into all activities of same application in android. How it is possible. I need source code. Please help some one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Activity` extended `BaseActivity` class that you use as a base class for every activity in your app.
Add the code related to your action bar and all common activity code to this `BaseActivity`. This way you can achieve consistency across all activities in your application.